# How to view an image uploaded in Django admin to template

Tags: python, django

Hello I would like to ask on how to view an image that I uploaded in django admin to selected html page, this is my html, there is no problem with the object title but I cant seem to load the image the error indicates that it is

```
Not Found: /media/products/greenfood_MHL4ssO.jpg
[09/Nov/2017 15:25:19] "GET /media/products/greenfood_MHL4ssO.jpg HTTP/1.1" 
404 3103

the image file is stored here 
>>C:\trydjango\static\media\products\greenfood_MHL4ssO.jpg 
the image url is 
/media/products/greenfood_MHL4ssO.jpg 

 <h3>{{object.title}}</h3>
            {% if object.productimage_set.count > 0 %}
            <div>
                {% for img in object.productimage_set.all %}
                {{ img.image.file}}

              <img class='img-responsive' src='{{ img.image.url }}'/>


                  {% endfor %}
            </div>

def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
    title = instance.product.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    file_extension = filename.split(".")[1]
    new_filename = "%s.%s" %(instance.id, file_extension)
    return "products/%s/%s" %(slug, new_filename)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.product.title
```

Comment: Make sure you has product_image related to object,so `object.productimage_set.count > 0` will be true.

Comment: Hi I have made some edits specifically on the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

the image should store in `C:\trydjango\media\products\greenfood_MHL4ssO.jpg`,media should not inside static folder.